# Dart - How to get the `runtimeType` of the elements of Iterable without elements?

Tags: flutter, dart, iterable, runtime-type

how do I get to know the `runtimeType` of the elements that an Iterable is supposed to `accept`
when it has no element?

This is what my fruitless imagination produced so far:

```dart
extension MyUglyAndInelegantIterableExtensions on Iterable {
  Type get valueType => 
    this.isNotEmpty ? this.first.runtimeType : dynamic;
}

void main() {
  print('${<int>[1].valueType}');
  print('${<int>[].valueType}');
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension MyElegantIterableExtensions<T> on Iterable<T> {
  Type get valueType => T;
}
```